# Make "pdflatex" compile a file whose name contains double quotes characters

Tags: pdftex, linux, command-line

## The context

Consider a directory with the following files

```
$ ls
1.tex  '2 2.tex'  "3 '' 3.tex"  '4 "" 4.tex'
```

All these files contain the following

```
$ cat 1.tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document} a \end{document}
```

as can be proved by the output of the following command

```
$ sha512sum 1.tex '2 2.tex' "3 '' 3.tex" '4 "" 4.tex' | awk '{print $1}' | uniq | wc -l
1
```

I can compile `1.tex`, `2.tex` and `3 ''.tex` executing the following commands, respectively

```
$ pdflatex 1.tex >/dev/null && echo $?
0
$ pdflatex '2 2.tex' >/dev/null && echo $?
0
$ pdflatex "3 '' 3.tex" >/dev/null && echo $?
0
```

However, I cannot find a way to compile `4 "" 4.tex`. I've tried the following

```
$ pdflatex '4 "" 4.tex'
$ pdflatex "4 \"\" 4.tex"
$ pdflatex 4\ \"\"\ 4.tex
```

all showing the following (`█` represents the position in which the cursor is left)

```
$ pdflatex '4 "" 4.tex'
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `"4 4.tex"'.
<*> "4  4.tex"

(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name: █
```

## The question

Is there any way I can make `pdflatex` to compile a file whose name contains a double quotes characters?

I've never found a `.tex` file whose name contains double quotes characters but I just want to find out the reason which is causing this behavior.

## Additional context

This problem has nothing to do with the shell I'm using because of the following 2 reasons

### Reason 1

I created the following script and set the shebang to `bash`, `zsh` and `dash` so that I could see the behavior on different shells. All showed the output which was presented above. Because of this, this is not a behavior that only occurs with `zsh` but also with `bash` and `dash` so it is not a shell dependent problem.

```
$ cat main.sh
#!/bin/zsh

pdflatex '4 "" 4.tex'
pdflatex "4 \"\" 4.tex"
pdflatex 4\ \"\"\ 4.tex
```

### Reason 2

Consider a C++ source file with the following content

```
$ cat 'my "" file.cpp'
int main() {
  return 123;
}
$
```

I can compile it and execute it with the following command

```
$ g++ 'my "" file.cpp' && ./a.out
$ echo $?
123
```

Because of this, we can conclude that the shell I'm using is able to parse file names which contains the `"` character as can be proved by the fact that there is at least one program which accepts those arguments.

Comment: Out of interest, do you need your files to have such awkward names?

Comment: No, I explained that in the section with name "The question".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

web2c based tex implementations can not access files with a double quote in their name. Double quotes are only used for quoting white space in the filename.

```
texdoc web2c
```

section 3.5.4 says:

> double quote (`"`) characters are ignored within the filename; there is no way to read files whose names contain a `"`.

Comment: Perhaps explain why: 'Various parts of the TeX ecosystem use spaces to terminate filenames, and to allow names-with-spaces, quoting in `"` chars was introduced'

Comment: @JosephWright yes but as shown in the question it _could_ allow other things shells allow you use single quotes to quote filenames that include double quotes and vice versa, you only have to do more contortions for filenames using both quotes. I think it's just that they didn't think the complication was worth it.

Comment: I executed `texdoc web2c` and didn't found that quote within the PDF document. However, I found it in what it seems to be the [online documentation of web2c](https://www.tug.org/texinfohtml/web2c.html) under the section 3.5.4 with name "`\input` filenames".

Comment: @R.Morales in the texlive 2020 versuon `texdoc web2c` should open `web2c.pdf` and that line  is the first line at the top of page 13 (section 3.5.4)